# SKLabelNode without transparent background

Tags: sprite-kit, sklabelnode

Hi I'm using a custom font on a SKLabelNode.

I'm able to set the font colour but ok, but the inner parts of the text, are transparent.

Is there a way i can set this colour to white for example?

my code so far

```
    scoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: You can use another font which looks the same (without the 3d effect) and superimpose it on this label.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found is to combine an SKSpriteNode and a SKLabelNode.
You simply add the SKLabelNode as a child to the SKSpriteNode.

```
    SKLabelNode *label = [[SKLabelNode alloc]initWithFontNamed:@"Courier"];
    label.text = @"blah";
    label.fontColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height)];
    background.position = CGPointMake(200, 100);
    [background addChild:label];
    label.position = CGPointMake(0, -label.frame.size.height/2);

    [self addChild:background];
```

The result looks like this...
[image]

Comment: Or do you just mean set the color as white in the inner parts of b and a?

Comment: close, i've added an example image to my question. So the white part of the text should be as displayed, however in mine it is yellow, as if transparent!