# Easy way to make an SKLabelNode non-transparent background?

Tags: sprite-kit

Is there an *easy* way to make an `SKLabelNode` non-transparent, so that the bounding frame is solid and covers the background scene?

I know I can [add another sprite and float the text over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252899/sklabelnode-without-transparent-background), but I'm just wondering if I'm missing some obvious built-in way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is built-in function to achieve this based on Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklabelnode

Comment: It should be very easy to create your own subclass of SKLabel consisting of the label and a SKNode behind it of a specific colour.

Comment: @SteveIves it was, but it still seems odd to me this isn't built in. There's no lack of questions on the topic here on SO.

Comment: You can convert your sklabelbode to an sktexture, then use that texture on a sprite instead